# How to apply a dark theme to a shiny application

Tags: shiny, themes

I would like to apply a dark theme to a shiny application (darkly, sandstone, cyborg ect) but the DT datatable produced does is almost impossible to read.

I am aware that this question has been asked before but the answer does not work for me. Using the DataTable example (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/datatables.html) could someone please let me know how to resolve this issue (i.e how to use a dark theme and produce a datatable that is readable?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check out `shinythemes::themeSelector()`?

Comment: Yes, did not work for me

Comment: Why not or what didnt work?